# Custom sizes in inkscape's real-time icon preview?

Tags: inkscape, icon

Is there a way to get a real-time icon preview at a specified size in inkscape? The *Icon Preview* panel found in the *View* menu seems perfect, except I can't find a way to get it to display sizes other than 128x128, 48x48, 24x24, and 16x16.

Comment: The configuration file (preferences.xml) includes a section "iconpreview" that contains many more sizes which are disabled. I tried to enable them (`show=1`) to no avail. I'm using Inkscape 1.0 beta.

Comment: Works for me in 1.0rc1 (7e930b84de, 2020-04-30) . Did you edit the correct file, and edited it while Inkscape was closed, @Juancho ?

Answer (score 2):

Editing inkscape's `preferences.xml` [as described by Juancho](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136949/custom-sizes-in-inkscapes-real-time-icon-preview#comment203781_136949) worked for me.

1. Find `preferences.xml`. The location of this file on your platform can be found in *Edit menu > Preferences > System > User preferences*.
2. Find a `<group>` tag with `id="iconpreview"`. Mine actually had two `<group>`s with that id, but only one had a sub `<group>` with `id="sizes"`.
3. Add (a) sub`<group>`(s) next to the existing `id="sizeN"` `<group>`s with your desired size(s) and `show="1"`, e.g.

   ```
   <group
      value="28"
      show="1"
      id="size28" />
   ```