# How to achieve a pixelated view for low resolution graphics in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, bitmap, rasterization

Is there a way to rasterize the Inkscape editor view for low res to emulate bitmap graphics?
E.g. an 8px text on a 32x32px page is shown perfectly vector-y ;-)

If a "pixelate" filter effect could be used, it would need to align to the pixel grid.

Comment: You might want to consider using a pixel font for text. There is no way normal text is going to look good when rasterized at 8px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to double-check how your work would look at very low resolutions, then there is the 'View → Icon Preview' panel, that gives you a magnified and pixelated preview of your page or selection at common icon sizes.

Alternatively you can also use 'Edit → Make a bitmap copy' to rasterize your selection, open the 'Object → Object Properties...' panel and set the 'Image Rendering' drop-down for the new image-object to 'pixelated'.

Comment: Custom square sizes in Icon Preview: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136949/custom-sizes-in-inkscapes-real-time-icon-preview